# Fast way of generating sequence of numbers in R

Tags: r, loops, optimization, vectorization

It may look like a funny question but what is the fastest way in `R` to generate a 2 rows matrix like below:

```
cc = NULL
n1 = 1000
n2 = 1000000
  for (i in 0:n1)
    for (j in 0:n2)
      cc = c(cc, i, j)
  cbn = matrix(cc, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you want to avoid for loops and building vectors via "c" over and over.  Here's one way to do that.

```
n1 <- 3
n2 <- 4

rbind(rep(0:n1, each = n2 + 1), rep(0:n2, n1 + 1))
```